# Right to left Text HTML input

Tags: css, input, arabic, right-to-left

For my website, i need to provide arabic support. Part of it is to provide input textboxes where when user types in, the new characters have to be appended to the left and the text has to be right aligned.

setting the css property to

```
text-align:right
```

didn't work, as i could not get the cursor to come to the left and add letters there. So I removed that property and added

```
direction:RTL
```

Here, the cursor came to the left and text was right aligned. but the newly added characters were not getting appended to the left. Instead they were getting appended to the right end only.

How do I fix this? please help..

For example, see the google arabic page search box. I need the exact behavior, although not with those fancy keyboard icon etc., http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=ar

Comment: Normally <bdo dir="rtl">TEXT HERE</bdo> would do exacly that, but when receiving text from a form or such, it won't work.

Comment: Could you post your solution?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here's what I can think of:

- Use `direction:RTL` for the RIGHT alignment
- Write a JavaScript handler attached to the event: "onkeyup", which performs the shifting of the entered character to the LEFT (doing some text processing).

Comment: Ahmed can you please share the way you managed to work it out?

Comment: A fiddle would be nice. Thanks

Comment: JS is not needed in any way, sorry but this is a really bad suggestion. Nicholas answer below, `dir="rtl"` is all that is needed: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir

Answer (score 63):

You can use the dir="rtl" on the input. It is supported.

```
<input dir="rtl" id="foo"/>
```

Comment: Also note though that CSS shims are still recommended as of 2018 for some browsers, see https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/

Answer (score 9):

```
function rtl(element)
{   
    if(element.setSelectionRange){
        element.setSelectionRange(0,0);
    }
}




<input type="text" name="textbox" style="direction:RTL;" onkeyup="rtl(this);"/>
```

This code will do.

Answer (score 8):

Simply use this CSS, this will change your text field and cursor position from right to left.

```
input, textarea { 
 unicode-bidi:bidi-override; 
 direction: RTL; 
}
```

Comment: Using unicode-bidi is  not recommended by MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi

Answer (score 5):

Use only `direction:RTL` and when switched to a proper keyboard (e.g. Arabic) in the system settings, the newly added characters will correctly be appended to the left.

Answer (score 5):

A feature specific to Angular Material, in addition to direction: rtl, is :

```
.mat-form-field {
   text-align: start!important;
 }
```

This will work for both RLT & LTR

Answer (score 5):

A better, more user-friendly way to do this is to set the `dir` attribute to `auto`.

```
<input dir="auto" id="foo"/>
```

This way if a user enters English text it will be left-aligned and if he enters Arabic text it will be right-aligned automatically

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir) for more information on the `dir` attribute

Answer (score 3):

Use on the input in css.

```
input {
  unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
  direction: RTL;
}
```

Comment: Using unicode-bidi is  not recommended by MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi

Answer (score -1):

It works for Chrome browser.
Use a div element and make it editable.

```
    <div contenteditable="true">
    </div>
```