# TextBox input Right to Left, but the dir="rtl" is not complete

Tags: asp.net, textbox, hebrew, right-to-left

I need to have a TextBox with Right to Left input. In ASP.NET you can do this with the dir="rtl", but it doesn't give the required effect.

Example:

The TextBox below has the dir="rtl" tag.

[image]

When I now press 'a', you get this:

[image]

But apparently in Hebrew, you're supposed to get this:

[image]

Is there some built-in functionality for this in ASP.NET? I can't seem to find it, everywhere I search they say it's the dir="rtl" tag.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this question/answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524855/right-to-left-text-html-input

Comment: That is exactly an answer to my problem, thank you. :)

Comment: Could you please share your solution? How did your keypress event method looked like? The answer in the link doesn't provide a full answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Sam Tyson in comment.