# How to Fix the Cursor Position on Text Input

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on entering dollar amounts into a text input field. Is there a way when I have direction set to RTL that I can maintain the cursor to be at the farthest right position and keep it there?

```
<input type="text" id="textArea">
```

CSS:

```
#textArea {
direction:RTL;}
```

This just starts the cursor on the right, but when you type it still moves in the standard fashion. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524855/right-to-left-text-html-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dealing with text inside of an input, just use `text-align: right;`

```
#textArea{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the [dir attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp)

```html
<input type="text" dir="rtl" id="textArea">
```

Comment: This doesn't address his issue. When you type, the text is right aligned but reads left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Add another attribute to your input that looks something like this:

```
onkeyup="rtl(this);"
```