# How to handle right-to-left text-input fields the right way?

Tags: html, css, hebrew, bidi

I am working on a multilingual layout. What worries me is:

> How to handle text-input the right way?

I've build a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0w5rydrL/) to explain my problem.

1. If I just add `dir="rtl"`, the words appear from right to left, but not each character
2. If I add the CSS style for right-to-left, the included numbers are also turned around

> How can i combine numbers and text, so a hebrew input is showing
>   correctly?

Comment: Have you tried typing in with hebrew keyboard enabled?

Comment: Yes, it's not working the way i expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524855/right-to-left-text-html-input)

Example http://jsfiddle.net/0w5rydrL/1/

The html

```
<div class="text_direction" dir="rtl">
    <input type="text" onkeyup="rtl(this);" />
</div>
```

The javascript function

```
function rtl(element){   
    if(element.setSelectionRange){
        element.setSelectionRange(0,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: caution: if you type fast, this solution mess with the characters