# How to have a right-to-left text-input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, uwp

I'm creating a Multilanguage support website and I'm invoking the Webpage in my UWP application thought WebView Control. 
But the problem is that, I cant get the  Right to Left input of text in my Text box.

I saw some sites which holds some answers [How to handle right-to-left text-input fields the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361649/how-to-handle-right-to-left-text-input-fields-the-right-way) But this fails when I input special characters which Shift pressed.

This code below works, but since it works only in Chrome and it fails in IE, Edge nor in UWP application.

```
@style = "direction: rtl;unicode-bidi: bidi-override
```

Is there any solution which would be universal. I hope that there would be some solution. Can anyone please suggest some.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer but what I know is that javascript(you tagged) is not portable across browsers but jQuery is, see if that matters

Comment: input in a text box right to left is like this inline:

Comment: `<input style="direction=rtl">`

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, direction=rtl aligns the text to right.But  I want the individual characters also to be reversed. Input : UserName Output : emaNresU

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" style="direction:RTL;" onkeyup="rtl(this);"/>
```

Comment: This solution would not work if any special characters like Shift+! is pressed. Kavi@ would be reversed as    ivaK@