# Reading the value from a textarea for mixed text (rtl + ltr) with the correct order

Tags: javascript, textarea, right-to-left

I have a textarea with with attribute dir="rtl" and my text looks there good [image: Correct order of characters]

But when I'm trying to retrieve the value of textarea in JS (for example through jQuery, or through native JS), I'm receiving it in the wrong way: "שם: NAME נהרי"

Is it possible to get it in JS (not in textarea) in right way?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so that we can debug it?

Comment: Yes, of course https://jsfiddle.net/jgpt008c/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle right-to-left text-input fields the right way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361649/how-to-handle-right-to-left-text-input-fields-the-right-way)

Comment: Unfortunately the solution by this link doesn't work for me

Comment: I'll revoke my vote, but can you explain why it is wrong way?

Comment: Which exactly? That way which has been described in question by the link? It's another question, it doesn't help to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get data from text area the language you are using is start from right to left js parser get this from right to left.
In English we write from left to right. This language is opposite so that's why you are getting this error. Write a value in a native way
Write it as "נהרי NAME :שם"

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, what do you mean "write a value in a native way". It's already written correctly in textarea.

Comment: I mean the value work from right to left      <<<<==== in this way and you are treating it like English language ====>>>> left to right. Parser will get text from right to left. Write  :שם in right site then NAME.

Comment: Yes, it's how it was written into the textarea. My problem is that when I'm trying to get this value through JS, the order is mixed as I described above.

Comment: Can you share js fiddle ?

Comment: There is no way to change DOM property rtl we only can change it in css.

Comment: We need to change it manually to reverse string property you can do this as :  

var a= document.getElementById("second").value;
      a = a.split("");
      a = a.reverse();
      a=a.join("");
document.write(a);

Comment: It's not exactly what I need, but I appreciate your efforts. Thank you.