# How to make direction of input text in jquery mobile right to left?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In jQuery mobile I used a input text :

```
<input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" id="txt_name_contractor">
```

and in my css file I set this properties :

```
direction : rtl
text-align : right
```

But when I type in this input text , It is left to right .
How I should fix this problem?

Comment: Can't replicate the issue http://jsfiddle.net/pwtq5csv/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function rtl(element) {   
    if(element.setSelectionRange) {
        element.setSelectionRange(0,0);
    }
}

$('.myInput').keyup(function(e) {
    rtl(this);
});
```

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524855/right-to-left-text-html-input), by [@Anshul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/672764/anshul)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45hsfmbe/1/)