# How to change Keyboard layout automatically in APEX 5?

Tags: css, oracle-apex

I have an application build in APEX 5.1.2 and I have some fields that should be inserted in RTL layout. The annoying thing is that when coming to that field, I have to change the keyboard layout every time. Is there any way to make a field to change its keyboard layout automatically at the time clicking it? I  think that could be done in CSS. Any one can help that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an APEX related question. Its related to CSS and JS and other things not particular to APEX.
You will have better luck posting this question in a CSS/JS  thread.

Here look at this thread,seems they describe the solution very clearly.

[css - Right to left Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524855/right-to-left-text-html-input)

Comment: Hmm, it's in the grey zone. Plenty of APEX questions have CSS/JS related answers, we're building web pages after all. There's also a respectable amount of RTL APEX developers who may contribute to the answer.