# How to change cursor position in textarea, when language is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `textarea` which can take both English and Arabic language.

The English language starts from left to right. So, the cursor should begin in the left.

The Arabic language starts from the right. So the cursor should begin in the right.

How can I change the position of the cursor when the user changes his language? If his language is English the cursor should be on the left and vice-versa.

The user can change his language using `ALT + SHIFT` in the keyboard.

I have tried this, but it didn't give me any result.

```
<textarea class="form-control description arabic" id="txt_desc" name="txt_desc" 
          placeholder="Description"></textarea>

.arabic{text-align:right;}

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var reverseFunc = function() {
            $('textarea').each(function() {
                if($(this).hasClass('arabic')) {
                    // do the invert magic...
                    var val = $(this).val();
                    var newVal = val.charAt(val.length-1) + substr(0, val.length-1);
                    $(this).val(val);
                }
            });
        }

        $('textarea').bind('keyup', reverseFunc);
    });
</script>
```

using shiftkey:

```
var x = document.getElementById("txt_desc");
    if (event.shiftKey) {
        document.getElementById('txt_desc').style.direction="rtl";
    }else{
         document.getElementById('txt_desc').style.direction="ltr";
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right to left Text HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524855/right-to-left-text-html-input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the first character on keyup, if it's Arabic add this `direction: rtl;`

```
var la_ar = 
["ي","و","ه","ش","س","ق","ف","غ","ع","ض","ص","ن","م","ل","ك","ظ","ط","ز","ر","ذ","د","خ","ح","ج","ث","ت","ب","ا"]
```

```js
$("input").keyup(function(){
var la_ar = 
["ي","و","ه","ش","س","ق","ف","غ","ع","ض","ص","ن","م","ل","ك","ظ","ط","ز","ر","ذ","د","خ","ح","ج","ث","ت","ب","ا"]
    var bla = $(this).val();
    var blaـl = bla.charAt(0);
    if($.inArray(blaـl, la_ar) > -1 ){
      //alert('in');
      $(this).css("direction","rtl");


    }else{
      //alert('out');
      $(this).css("direction","ltr");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: @mohamad mohamad " هل هذا ما تريد" is this what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
 use the css attribute direction

    direction: rtl;

    In Javascript your code add this

    var x = document.getElementById("txt_desc");
        if (event.shiftKey) {
            document.getElementById('txt_desc').style.direction="rtl";
        }else{
             document.getElementById('txt_desc').style.direction="ltr";
        }
```

Comment: thank you the rtl work but i want the cursor appear in the left or right

Comment: can we do that without the button on off only when the user change the language click alt+shif ??

Comment: Yes you can using event.shiftKey and call the method

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: onkeypress='alert(event.keyCode)' check the keycode and cal this method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153611/discussion-between-laxman-kanhere-and-mohamad-mohamad).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Html5 property this will work.

```
.arabic{ direction: rtl;}
```

Comment: thank you the rtl work but i want the cursor appear in the left or right

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<textarea style="direction: rtl"></textarea>
```